# human like mouse scroll in java and selenium

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver

First I would like to say that I started programming 3 days ago. So I'm pretty much a beginner. I do not plan on engaging in programming other than what I present here, I just need a simple program for now and I wanted to do it by myself, purely as a hobby. I'm doing it with Selenium and java. So, I need a code that will scroll down/up the web application in the web browser as much as human real as possible. I'm currently using this code:

```
JavascriptExecutor js = (JavascriptExecutor) driver;
js.executeScript ("window.scrollBy (0.1500)", "");
```

and it's okay, however what this code do looks like pressing page down button instead of scrolling.

And after that, I thought to do the following:

```
js.executeScript ("window.scrollBy (0.50)", "");
js.executeScript ("window.scrollBy (0.30)", "");
js.executeScript ("window.scrollBy (0.33)", "");
js.executeScript ("window.scrollBy (0.42)", "");
js.executeScript ("window.scrollBy (0.45)", "");
js.executeScript ("window.scrollBy (0.24)", "");
js.executeScript ("window.scrollBy (0.19)", "");
js.executeScript ("window.scrollBy (0.50)", "");
```

so now this code scrolls the page down like scrolling with mouse using the scroll wheel, but as you can see, it does not look like an "elegant" solution, and I'm sure that there is something better, but with my 3 days experience this is the best I can do.

So, is there anyone willing to help me  more efficient code instead of using millions of lines to do the same repeat job... I don't know, something like:

```
js.executeScript ("window.scrollBy (0,50,45,66,78,43,56,87)", "");
```

where in one line and several variables the program can do what need to be done and take the time intervals and/or the pixels on which to scroll from "0,50,45,66,78,43,56,87 "

Comment: What is you exact usecase? Why do you want to scroll?

Answer (score 1):

Try to implement `arguments[0].scrollIntoView(true);` in the `executeScript()` method.
 If you want to scroll down to last, select `FOOTER` as the target element.

```
WebElement elem =  driver.findElement(By.id("ID OF FOOTER ELEMENT"));

JavascriptExecutor js = (JavascriptExecutor) driver;
js.executeScript("arguments[0].scrollIntoView(true);", elem);
```

You can use `By.className("CLASSNAME OF FOOTER ELEMENT")` or `By.xpath("XPATH SELECTOR OF FOOTER")` or `By.cssSelector("CSS SELECTOR OF FOOTER")` if id is not available.

**Note:** You can scroll to any position locating the target element selector.

Comment: I know how to scroll to a specific element or to the top/bottom of the page, I want to know how to scroll exactly like using a mouse so I can watch how my page elements are loading.

Answer (score 0):

First let us use an `array` to store your `coordinates` or `values`.

> **JavaScript Arrays**
>
> An array can hold many values under a single name, and you can access
>   the values by referring to an index number following this simple syntax:
>
> `var array_name = [item1, item2, ...];`

For your example that could then look like this:

```
var values = [0.50, 0.33, 0.33, 0.42, 0.45, 0.24, 0.19, 0.50];
```

Now you could create your own `function` for the scrolling that uses all of the values stored in the `array` created above. combined with a loop this would get repeated.

```
function scrollFunction() {

    // Creating our needed variables
    var values, vLength, I;

    // Filling the array
    values = [0.50, 0.33, 0.33, 0.42, 0.45, 0.24, 0.19, 0.50];
    vLength = values;

    // By using this for-loop this process will repeat with with all of the variables from the array. However the next value is used, not the same one every time!
    for (i = 0; i < vLength; i++) {
        window.scrollBy (values[i], ""); // Update: deleted one ")"
    }
}
```

To create a smooth scrolling effect I would recommend to use the scroll function differently:

```
window.scrollBy({ top: values[i], left: 0, behavior: 'smooth' });
```

Comment: can I use JavaScript Arrays in selenium? I have tried your code but I get a of of error, like:

Syntax error on token ")", delete this token
 Syntax error on token "}", delete this token

 at UsingActionsClass.UsingActions.main(UsingActions.java:20)

Comment: nope, now i get error:

Syntax error, insert "SimpleName" to complete Expression
 Syntax error, insert "VariableDeclarators" to complete LocalVariableDeclaration

 at UsingActionsClass.UsingActions.main(UsingActions.java:20)

in case you wonder here is my complete code -> https://pastebin.com/eawqKpv4

Comment: i tried also this https://pastebin.com/5XAMPr98 , still the same errors.